# Problema com foreach() imprimindo duas vezes

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
$ms = [8,12,13];

// $ms = json_decode($ar,true); // sobrou da versão anterior da pergunta

for($i=1; $i<21; $i++)
{
   foreach($ms as $obj){ 
      if( $i == $obj ) { 
         echo $obj;
      }
   } 
   echo $i; 
}
```

Preciso pegar do array() e continuar sem dar duplicidade.

- Saida: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 **8** 8 9 10 11 **12 12 13 13** 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
- Esperado: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 **8** 9 10 11 **12 13** 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

Acontece que, se eu eu tirar o trecho

```
foreach($ms as $r){ 
   if( $i == $obj ) { 
      echo ....
   }
}
```

consigo o resultado pretendido, mas preciso pegar o valor do array e aplicar alguns styles se o valor for encontrado.

Comment: Você quer uma coisa e perguntou outra. Eu expliquei na resposta a duplicação de onde vem. Se o objetivo era só formatar diferente, devia ter posto na pergunta (e a solução seria completamente diferente do seu loop e até mais simples). É o que chamamos de [ProblemaXY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499). Tentei aproveitar o código e atualizei a resposta, mas recomendo leitura do link para as próximas.

Comment: A pergunta não é sobre PHP7 especificamente, nada na pergunta contêm algo relacionado a funcionalidades/features do PHP7, tudo descrito funciona desde o php5.4, portanto a tag nem deveria ser PHP-7, deveria ser SÓ [PHP] ... PS: a ultima edição da pergunta não faz sentido, um array de verdade dentro do PHP não pode ser decodificado novamente com json_decode, só strings contendo json podem, esse código nem vai chegar a executar, o `$ms` vai ser null, aviso obtido: `PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Answer (score 3):

O código está imprimindo duas vezes o valor como era de se esperar.

Uma vez no `echo $r['status']`, e outra no `echo $i;`

Como você comentou que vai usar para formatação, provavelmente quer que imprima um echo ou outro. Então, para evitar que o `echo` de fora seja impresso, pode usar o `continue` dentro do `if`. O `2` significa que vai iterar o 2º loop, não só o de dentro:

```
$ar = [8,12,13];

for( $i = 1; $i < 21; $i++) {
   foreach($ar as $obj) { 
      if( $i == $obj ) { 
         echo '<b>'.$i.'</b> ';
         continue 2; // Já imprimiu, entao itera o loop sem passar
                     // pelo echo seguinte.
      }
   } 
   echo $i.' '; 
}
```

Veja funcionando online no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/G70lTo)**.

Manual: [`continue`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado pela atenção! Entendi o funcionamento do 'continue'.